# Xcode how to specify inline images in a Markdown file

Tags: ios, xcode, markdown

I'm thinking of creating a help file in Markdown, to add to an Xcode project.

I'd prefer to include image files in the project,  rather than refer to urls.

I know for example that I can do this:

`![my image name](http://example.com/aFolder/myImage.png)`,

but I'd like to do something like this:

```
![my image name](file://myImage.png)
```

or

```
![my image name](myImage.png)
```

Any ideas on what to try, or am I barking up the wrong tree trying to use Markdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
![image alt text](myImage.png)
```

is correct. However, the path (`myImage.png`) is relative to your markdown file, so in this case, `myImage.png` would be in the same directory as the markdown file. If, for instance, it's in its own folder called `images`, you'd do `![my image name](images/myImage.png)`

Comment: Thanks Connor.. At present the Markdown file and the image file are in the same folder, and my construction doesn't work.. Both files are in a subFolder of my project's root..

Comment: Is the project in question open source? I'd double check the name and extension of the image file.

Comment: I've also heard of people having issues with this because they left a space between the `]` and `(` - worth checking

Comment: The test project is open source: https://github.com/SimonFairbairn/SwiftyMarkdown. That seems to be ok, as it renders everything else fine. I wish there was a space between ` ]` and` (` , but no such luck. Any other ideas - should I post more code? Thanks..

Comment: Can you push up your branch that has the local image and markdown change? I see on develop it's working with the absolute URL.

Comment: Thx. I will when I get back. Could you give me an example of how to use an absolute URL! That may be all I need..

Comment: By that I meant your first example, ie. `![my image name](http://example.com/aFolder/myImage.png)`

Comment: thanks for all the help.. Do you have a recommendation for an open source Markdown parser? Either way, I'll mark the question resolved.

Comment: Got it. Your answer was absolutely correct. Thanks!! I changed my parser to   this one: https://github.com/keitaoouchi/MarkdownView